# print(b[1:,:1]) What does the b[1:,:1] mean in this array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

We are using numpy in Python as `b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`. Then we use the command `print(b[1:,:1])`, I'm just trying to understand what the `b[1:,:1]` is referencing in the array.

The output is:

```
 [[4]
  [7]]
```

and I'm just trying to understand how that output is coming out if that makes sense.

I've tried looking it up on google but I havent been able to find an answer that explains well enough what is happening and how the array is being accesed by the `[1:,:1]`.

Comment: This slices all rows after the second and all columns up to the second (excluded).

Comment: I assume you know what `xxx[1:]` means in a string or list, and also what `xxx[:1]` means.  This is just using both -- one in the 1st dimension, one in the 2nd dimension.  This is a numpy thing; Python doesn't allow multi-dimensional access in lists.

Comment: Look it up in the official numpy documentation.  For example, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html - the basics indexing section.  Google searches have their uses, but they aren't a substitute for actually learning the language and/or package from the documentation (or a good comprehensive book).  Also beware of tutorials -  -